# http/1 and http/2 parallel delivery using nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, http, http2, spdy

Is it possible to have both `http/1` and `http/2` enabled for a vhost in nginx?

The idea is to broaden the supported browsers by serving `http/2` if supported, and, if not, fall back to `http/1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is automatically handled in the TLS handshake. The client sends a TLS extension called ALPN (Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation) in its initial handshake message, where it tells it supports HTTP/2.

The server then selects the protocol to use in the connection depending on client capabilities.